# Simple roots of E6 root system

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

The simple roots of root system E6 are six 8-dimensional vetors. As I understand, simple roots should form a basis for the underlying vector space(in this case it is $\mathbb{R}^8$). For example, in root system E8, of which E6 is a subset, it does hold that simple roots are 8 eight-dimensional pairwise orthogonal vectors. Can someone explain how does it hold that in E6 we only have 6 eight-dimensional vectors? Do simple roots not form a basis then? Thank you!

Comment: You can find a lower-dimensional root system sitting in a higher-dimensional space. The most common one to come across is $A_{n-1}$ sitting in $n$-space with simple roots $e_i - e_{i+1}$. The simple roots form a basis for the subspace spanned by the root system, which in the $A_{n-1}$ case is those vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose coordinates sum to zero.

Comment: Simple roots form a basis of a space isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n$ is the rank of the root system. So the roots of $E_6$ span a 6-dimensional space. You are only viewing them in an 8-dimensional space to see them as a subset of $E_8$. However they are emphatically not an orthogonal basis and nor are the simple roots for $E_8$.

Comment: Thank you! But how do you translate them into vectors in $\mathbb{R}^6.$ Is there any general embedding?

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#E6,_E7,_E8) gives a couple possible realisations for $E_6$